# The text inside the <h2> tag not visible in the UI

Tags: aura

```
<aura:set attribute="else">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.tempField.Order_Field_API_Name__c=='Lab__c'}" >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(greaterthan(item.pickListOptions.length,1),empty(item.pickListOptions))}"><option text="Please select a Lab" value="" /></aura:if>
        <h2>Favorite labs:</h2>
        <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!greaterthan(option1.count, 0)}">
                <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{!option1.count}</option>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
        
        <h2>Other Labs:</h2>
        <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(option1.count, 1)}">
                <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{!option1.count}</option>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
        <aura:set attribute="else"> 
            <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">                            
                <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{</option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if> 
</aura:set>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an `h2` inside a `select`. This is not permitted by HTML standards. Instead, use `optgroup`, as in:

```
<aura:set attribute="else">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.tempField.Order_Field_API_Name__c=='Lab__c'}" >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(greaterthan(item.pickListOptions.length,1),empty(item.pickListOptions))}"><option text="Please select a Lab" value="" /></aura:if>
        <optgroup label="Favorite labs">
        <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!greaterthan(option1.count, 0)}">
                <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{!option1.count}</option>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
        </optgroup>
        
        <optgroup label="Other Labs">
            <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(option1.count, 1)}">
                    <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{!option1.count}</option>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:iteration>
            <aura:set attribute="else"> 
                <aura:iteration items="{!item.pickListOptions}" var="option1">                            
                    <option label="{!option1.label}" value="{!option1.value}">{!option1.label}{</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </aura:set>
        </optgroup>
    </aura:if> 
</aura:set>
```